# constraint layout issue after migrating to android x

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout, androidx

Hi all after migrating to androidx, from compat library.

I faced issues which are related to constraint layout, like `custom:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` stopped working in place of it i have to add `custom:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.

EDIT

This is just for sharing my information after migrating to androidx.

Comment: Please add whole Constraint Layout tag. So We can guide you and what is your targeted sdk?

Comment: Show us the xml code so we can help?

Answer (score -1):

replace your constraint tag with this. try it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
```

like this.

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
```

Comment: migrating to androidx , by using android studio script does that.

Comment: place your layout code here just change custom to app